# How to fix this arrow shape created using CSS in IE9

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, css-shapes

I've created a shape using below css which displays fine in chrome like this:[image]

But this appears broken in IE9 like this:

[image]

How do i fix this?
Here is my css/html used for generating this.

```css
.arrow-head {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid blue;
  float: left;
}

.arrow-mid {
  background: blue;
  height: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.arrow-tail {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-top: 10px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 10px solid blue;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-tail"></div>
<div class="arrow-mid"></div>
<div class="arrow-head"></div>
```

Comment: Seems to work in IE9 **mode** of IE11

Comment: Wasn't me who downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used IE9 using Developer Tools and seems like it's working perfectly for me.

Guess you messed up your developer tools and I assume you have IE8 Standards View turned on...

Use the below `meta` and see it will work

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/iHOrinoq/1/edit) *(This is only for OP, as the code runs pefectly on IE9 Standards Mode)*

Comment: @Pranalee Because you have 8 standard mode running